# Writing Remember Me for login

Tags: php, authentication, remember-me

I'm going to write a login page, and I've been reading Charlie Miller's article on Remember Me for logins. Also read the OWASP cheat sheet.
I was thinking, instead of a persistent database entry for the random number, could you not just store the random number in the $_SESSION array? Then check the user cookie, if it matches, then regenerate numbers and set in session cookie and user cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, usually you don't have a valid session for the user when he has to login again. Sessions don't get stored infinitely.

Comment: So, should I follow Charlie Miller's best practice to the letter then?

Comment: At least it would be the cleanest approach.